# Entity Framework code first adding models from other projects

Tags: database, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, prism, code-first

Normally one would write its model classes and create a DbContext with several DbSet's to the corresponding modelclasses to create the database in EF code first.

The Prism library allows you to create modules. Modules live in the same solution but as another Project inside the solution, or maybe it could be a DLL from another solution.

My question now: what if you have for example a prism module (a separated project) with its own models (and DbSet definitions).
How can you add or inject (or let EF discover) these model classes and DbSet's from that module and add them to the existing EF database)?

Lets say some external person writes a plugin (a prism module) with its own database models and offcourse the corresponding DbSet definitions. 
If that person drops that prism module DLL in the program directory, how would the core application (at startup normally) know that there are other DbSet's from the prism module that also need to be created in the database if they don't exist yet. (And how can they be added?)

Thanks in advance.

Could somebody give a code sample of how to do this? I was thinking about the MEF attributes [ImportMany] and [ExportMany] but i'm not sure if that could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had this issue and didn't find a satisfying solution.

The problem is, especially if you use RIA services, all the classes need to be in place at compile time, so that Visual Studio can generate the code for you. The only solution I found for that was inheritance, but I abandoned that idea because it introduces far to many problems to be efficient. If you don't use abstract classes, RIA services even replicates the inheritance structure. But still you would need a base class for every entity you want (e.g. CustomerBase in the main module -> Customer : CustomerBase in the CustomerModule).

(Detail: The reason for this is that if you want foreign keys, you must have some idea of the other class in e.g. Customer in the BillingModule).

If you don't like the inheritance way, you can define interfaces that you implement manually on the client using partial classes (to later only expose this interface in your repositories). I stuck with that and I'm quite happy now. Still now the way I wished ti to be though.

Comment: hmmmm so actually you are saying that my question cannot be done with EF code first?